# Zurb Foundation Sticky Nav Bar

Tags: navigation, pug, sticky, zurb-foundation

So I'm using the default `.top-bar` class from the zurb foundation framework, but I'm failing a find a simple way to make the nav bar 'sticky' (follows the user as he scrolls), such as you can do with Twitter bootstrap.

Here's my code, I'm using jade:

```
nav.top-bar
  ul
    li.name
      h1
        a(href='#') Site Title
    li.toggle-topbar
      a(href='#')

  section
    ul.left
      li.divider
      li
        a.active(href='#') Link
      li.divider
      li
        a.active(href='#') Link
      li.divider
      li
        a.active(href='#') Link
      li.divider
      li
        a.active(href='#') Link
      li.divider
  section
    ul.right
      li.divider
      li.has-dropdown
        a.active(href='#') Log in
```

Am I missing something completely obvious here?

Comment: It's quite easy, you probably just skimmed over it in the docs. I've posted the answer and link below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs page: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php

**Positioning the Bar**

The top bar is built with a single nav element with a class of top-bar. It will take on full browser width by default. To make the top bar stay fixed as you scroll, wrap it in div **`class="fixed"`**. If you want your navigation to be set to your grid width, wrap it in div class="contain-to-grid". You may use fixed and contain-to-grid together.

Comment: That link is dead now since Zurb updated all of their documentation for Foundation 4.  To do this in 4, put div class="contain-to-grid sticky" anywhere in your navigation markup.  More details: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html.

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/navigation.php still exists and is still supported

Comment: It says "anywhere in your markup" not "anywhere in your navigation markup" Which means that you can add a sticky bar at any place in the HTML.

Comment: @David's link is now unfortunately dead too. Heres the page for F5: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/topbar.html - and the F6: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also give it the class "**sticky**" and have the menu located anywhere on your page, and when it hits the top it will stick and follow.

> You may also wrap your top bar in div class="contain-to-grid sticky"
>   and put it anywhere within your markup. When the navigation hits the
>   top of the browser, it will act like the fixed top bar and stick to
>   the top as users continue to scroll.
>   [Link to Source](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html)

Answer (score 0):

To make your .top-bar work nicely and smoothly, you need to wrap it with separate div, like

```
<div class="sticky">
 <div class="contain-to-grid">
  <nav>
   ...
  </nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

I found this works quite well with my resized browser and iphone Chrome.